# Statsmodels : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x13'

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am implementing a seasonal ARIMA prediction for time series in Python. I am using Statsmodels 0.7.0.

What I have done so far is:

```
import statsmodels.api  as sm
res= sm.tsa.x13.x13_arima_select_order(time_series)
```

But I am getting this error :

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x13'

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with statsmodels, but try this instead:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.x13 import x13_arima_select_order

res = x13_arima_select_order(time_series)
```

Source: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/tests/test_x13.py

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I modified my code as you suggested and now I am not getting the attribute error any more :) . 
However, I am getting a new exception:
 X13NotFoundError("x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the "
statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.X13NotFoundError: x12a and x13as not found on path. Give the path, put them on PATH, or set the X12PATH or X13PATH environmental variable. I do not know how to set the X13PATH.

Comment: Hi. I suggest you start a new question and post your full code and the full error message so that it's easier for someone to help you. When you create your new question, highlight the code and click the icon that looks like curly braces "{}" to format it so it's easier for someone to read.  Cheers!

Comment: May i ask if you solve the issue? I met same problem.